# Is there a name for the technique of converting method parameters into a unified form to simplify further processing?

Tags: terminology, parameters

When working with methods which accept a parameter in various forms (e.g. `nil`, a single string, a single string containing multiple data or an array of strings) I tend to unify them - splitting, sanitizing and putting them into an array because this simplifies further processing and removes the need for nil, type and size checks.

example (in Ruby):

```
params = Array(original_param).map { |a| a.split(/\s*,\s*/) }.flatten
params.each{|p| process(p)}
```

However, [I have no idea what I am doing](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-have-no-idea-what-im-doing), at least I have no idea if there is a name for what I am doing. Is there?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: The votes from the link and the links within suggest that terminology questions are on-topic, though many think otherwise. I think there are two types of terminology questions - the ones trying to invent a name for a thing and the ones asking people with better english skills and more professional experience for an existing term. The two types are not distinguishable if you do not know the term :)

Comment: I'd call it "normalization".

Comment: Thnk you, Jörg - the best proposition yet :) A colleague of mine said 'coercion', but I have never heard anybody use it.

Comment: Possible alternatives to @Jörg's suggestion are [canonicalization or standardization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization). Really though, unless you're running shell commands a function that accepts either a delimited string or an array of strings sets off red flags in my head, and for the particular case of shell commands it already has a term (word splitting). It's better to just say what format you need and leave it up to the caller to do whatever conversion is needed.

Comment: I think this is a not-too-bad question for naming, as it provides a clear context and a concise example, so if I could vote against closing it, I would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common terms for this are *canonicalisation* and *normalisation*. In mathematics, a [normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form) is a standard way of representing an object with multiple equivalent representations. For example, these two logical expressions are equal:

> ¬x ∨ ¬y ∨ ¬z
>
> ¬(x ∧ y ∧ z)

But the former is in [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) while the latter is not.

In programming, we typically talk about canonicalisation only when there is a singular canonical representation, for example, on a file system (ignoring hard links), the canonical representation of the path referred to by `../bar` might be `/foo/bar`. In other cases, where the choice of normal form is arbitrary, normalisation is the preferred term.

In the context of security, *sanitisation* refers to normalisation for the purposes of rendering malicious input harmless. This usually consists of enforcing language separation by escaping special characters or using type system features.

Comment: Normalization seems to be the best fit. Thank you, Jon.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase you are looking for is [tokenization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization), and as you noted, it's a very common process for sanitizing input parameters.

From the linked Wikipedia article:

> Tokenization is the process of breaking a stream of text up into words, phrases, symbols, or other meaningful elements called tokens. The list of tokens becomes input for further processing such as parsing or text mining.

Comment: Tokenization seems to be only one of the possible things that the OP might be doing to his function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

At Microsoft, the term I heard a lot for this was "Legoing" as in "I Legoed that crap spaghetti code down into a nice, maintainable bit of code".

I think this is very similar to what you're asking for, I just don't know how portable "to Lego" is outside of MSFT.  I'm not a big fan of "[verbing a noun](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/verbingfaq.htm)", but it seems to fit here.